# Passing multiple array value from datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

currently I am using datatables with multiple selection. When I select 3 rows based on [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNkto.png) (from top to bottom), my console.log returns [this value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDo4V.png) (return result every time row is being selected). The value that I need to post to next page is this, since it's the latest result:

```
["SN20171110", "SN20171111", "SN20171113"]
```

and so I did console.log again to check the value in ajax post without getting to next page but the result was random (the order):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVkrW.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irf1k.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nn1n.png

So what I get in the next page was the bottom(latest) result from console.log mentioned above.

Is there any way to pass only the bottom result or javascript variable?

Here is my Datatable selection code:

```
  var newdata = $.map(example.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        return item[1];
    });

    var test = newdata;
    console.log(test);

    $('#nextButton').click(function(e){
      $.ajax({
        url     : 'enrollmentDevice.php',
        method  : 'POST',
        data    : { test },
        beforeSend: function(){
          console.clear();
        },
        success : function(new2) {
          console.log(test);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem

Comment: It sounds like there are some async operations happening and once each is complete it console.logs the result.  Since they are async they might not complete in the same order.  Need to see code to recommend an approach as any answer would be vague as is.

Comment: Apologize, updated with codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem by posting the value to hidden form and POST to next page using

```
<form action="nextpage.php" method="POST"></form>
```

instead of using Ajax.
But still not sure what cause the problem. Any input would be appreciate. Thank you.